# Where to call add_shortcode function in WordPress Plugin Boilerplate?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

I am creating a new plugin and have decided to use [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](https://wppb.me/).

However, I'm not sure where the correct place is to call WP's `add_shortcode`. I'm  stuck on two counts:

1. `add_shortcode` doesn't usually have a hook - so I doubt I would call it via my `define_admin_hooks` or  `define_public_hooks` functions.
2. I'm not sure how I would specify the callback function for `add_shortcode` now that everything is object orientated.

So where is the best place for me to call `add_shortcode`? A short example/snippet would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is no canonical WordPress based answer to this, and no "correct" or "best" place as far as WordPress plugins go. You should ask the boilerplate people where they intended it to go. Remember, the boilerplate is not official, 3rd party, and the opinion of a single person that got popular. Other boilerplates exist, and you can create a plugin with no boilerplate at all

Answer (score 3):

Add the below function in `/includes/class-plugin-loader.php` :

```
public function add_shortcode( $tag, $component, $callback, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 2 ) {
        $this->shortcodes = $this->add( $this->shortcodes, $tag, $component, $callback, $priority, $accepted_args );
}
```

You can then define your shortcode in `/includes/class-plugin.php` within this function:

```
/**
 * Register all of the hooks related to the public-facing functionality
 * of the plugin.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 * @access   private
 */
private function define_public_hooks() {

    $plugin_public = new Plugin_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_scripts' );

    $this->loader->add_shortcode( 'YOUR-SHORTCODE-NAME', $plugin_public, 'YOUR_CALLBACK_FUNCTION' );

}
```

Finally add your callback function in the `/public/class-plugin-public.php` like this:

```
public function YOUR_CALLBACK_FUNCTION( $atts ){ 
    // do your shortcode stuff
}
```

Change `plugin` in the filenames above with your own plugin name.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the perfect answer for me, but there is no `add_shortcode` function in my **/includes/class-plugin-loader.php** file. Maybe the boilerplate generator I used - https://wppb.me/ - is using an out-of-date version. Which version of the boilerplate code are you referring to?

Comment: Just found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53191594/1617737 .